# Getting rotation of circle from center

Tags: math

I'm trying to find the rotation of a circle given the center of it. The circle needs to be perpendicular to a vector through the origin, 
[image: illustration].
For a circle that is originally based in the XY plane, I want to find the roll, pitch, and yaw to transform it to the center location. Any ideas? Doing this in ue4 so I don't need code, just an overall flow.

Comment: Hi! Have you considered asking on http://math.stackexchange.com/??

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not your "roll, pitch, yaw" system, but a *spherical polar coordinate* rotation. It is easier to think in the frame-of-reference of the coordinate axes rather than that of the circle.

A picture to illustrate:
[image]

Distance to axis:

[image]

Coordinates:

[image] ; [image] ; [image]

And to get the angles:

[image] ; [image]

Procedure:

1. Translate the circle in the positive Z-direction by [image]
2. Rotate about the Y-axis (in a clockwise sense when looking along it) by [image]
3. Rotate about the Z-axis (in a similar sense to above) by [image]

The rotation matrices required: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions